# See available drives from Windows CLI?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to list the available drives from cmd.exe ?
(Other than manually typying

```
c:
d:
...
```

and seeing which ones return errors)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

```
> wmic logicaldisk get caption

Caption
C:
D:
E:
```

if probably the easiest one. Doesn't need administrative privileges, doesn't return more or less than what's needed, etc.

If you want to use it in a script, then wrap it in `for /f` with the `skip=1` option:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do @echo.%%x
```

Comment: only for users with administrator rights

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós: works fine for me from a limited user account.

Comment: Quoting from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290216 "Wmic.exe can only be used by the local system administrators regardless of WMI namespace permissions on the local machine", and it failed on my machine (a VM with winXP)

Comment: It worked just fine under a non-admin account on a Windows 8.1 here. Note that the KB article applies only to legacy operating systems.

Comment: @Joey, Why `caption` instead of `wmic logicaldisk get name
`?

Comment: Got: `Failed to register mof file(s). Only the administrator group members can use WMIC.EXE. Reason:Win32 Error: Access is denied.`

Comment: This looks good too, including the volume name: `wmic logicaldisk get caption,volumename`.

Comment: doesn't work on MSDos

Comment: @TomášZato: Of course not. The question was about the Windows command line (it even says so in both the title and the question), not MS DOS.

Comment: Use "NET USE" for listing the network mapped drives.

Comment: 'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: if I use `for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic DISKDRIVE get Model') do @echo.DISKDRIVE: %%x` it prints out an additional line with `DISKDRIVE:` in it. I'm not sure how to fix this. Same with the original code, it prints an additional empty line to the cli.

Comment: I feel sad that this is considered the easiest way.  Can you imagine if listing the current directory contents only had a command like this?

Comment: @cowlinator: Luckily for you, `Get-PSDrive` is a much shorter way in PowerShell. By now, `cmd` can be considered mostly obsolete.

Comment: @Joey, ah, I see.  I thought that the `-psprovider filesystem` args were an absolute requirement.  Yes, `get-psdrive` is the simplest way.

Comment: This is really helpful for me to find the correct volume, thanks!

Answer (score 92):

If you're in Command Prompt:

```
diskpart
```

then

```
list volume
```

sample output:

```
  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     E                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     C   System       NTFS   Partition     99 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 3     F   Data (local  NTFS   Partition    365 GB  Healthy
```

and finally

```
exit
```

to return to the command line.

Comment: in contrast to the *net use* command, this will only list local physical drives.  (i think.)  see [diskpart at technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [diskpart at support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415)

Comment: `diskpart` needs administrative privileges. If you just want a list of drive letters that's a bit much to ask for ...

Comment: 'diskpart' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Answer (score 36):

For the sake of completeness, there is yet another way:

```
fsutil fsinfo drives
```

which returns:

```
Drives: C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\
```

(Not a very scripting-friendly output, but it may be useful for human eye)

Some [reference](http://www.windows-commandline.com/file-system-command-fsutil-fsinfo/).  That should work [since win2k](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788080.aspx) but only with Administrator account.

(Thanks @Carlos Campderrós for enhancing the answer)

Comment: It should be noted that this only work if you are using an Administrator account

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I don't think that's correct. I can run `fsutil` with a limited user, and the result is much faster than spinning up the `wmic` system. On my box with only SSDs running windows 10 v 1803, `wmic` takes 100-200ms, and `fsutil` takes ~20ms.

Comment: @mrm, some windows version (or release, or build of w10) probably losened this restriction.  I tested this on wxp and w7pro, and it failed without an admin account (AFAIR).

Comment: I second the observation by @saulius2

Answer (score 14):

If you're using powershell then you can type in

```
get-psdrive -psprovider filesystem
```

Edited in response to comments to only show filesystems

Comment: That will also return other non-filesystem drives that are mounted, such as Cert:, Alias: and Function:. Furthermore, it will return other file-system directories mounted as a PSDrive (such as Home: for %UserProfile% for me).

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. All other solutions seem to require administrator access. (At least on my horribly outdated Windows XP system.)

Comment: You can just use `get-psdrive` if you don't mind seeing non-filesystem drives listed.

Answer (score 12):

```
wmic logicaldisk get volumename,name
```

You can get (query) multiple properties this way. 
This will give you the partition/drive letter and the label you gave the drive/partition when you formatted the drive:

```
Name  VolumeName
C:    OS
D:    Data
E:    Programs
```

For help and to list all the permission options:

```
wmic logicaldisk /?
```

then

```
wmic logicaldisk get /?
```

Comment: I was trying to get the drive letter of the CD/DVD ROM and the closest thing I could find to get that is `wmic logicaldisk get name,filesystem`. Normal drives will list as `NTFS` or `FAT32`, and the CD/DVD ROM's filesystem will be empty.

Comment: Correction: if the drive is empty, filesystem is empty. If not, e.g. I have Windows 10 disc in it at the moment, and it's listed as `UDF`.

Answer (score 8):

Use the doskey built in function to create an alias that runs the wmic command with the necessary atributes

```
doskey v=wmic logicaldisk get caption
```

This will create an aliases "v" that whenever typed will run the given command and list all volume letters.

Comment: oh nice, didn't know about doskey (like powershell's Set-Alias)

Comment: Highly underrated answer, been using CMD for years and never realised aliases were a thing with it.

Answer (score 5):

To see available drives and their mount points from the cli I use

`mountvol`

You can also use the unmounted volume GUID for some commands like chkdsk and stuff.

Comment: What Windows versions have you used it on? On w10 `[Version 10.0.19042.1348]` it shows me only a help screen, sadly.

Comment: scroll down. it's listed after the help. it took me a few minute to realize it. by reflex, we tend to start reading right after where we typed the command.

Answer (score 4):

When you're using **powershell**, you can use the simple command

```
get-volume
```

and get a nice list with 8 columns:

```
DriveLetter Label FileSystem DriveType Health OperStatus FreeSpace Size
```

I write `Label` where get-volume writes `FriendlyName` (and I have abbreviated some of the titles in the list in order to minimize the risk of scrolling horizontally to see the end of the line).

Answer (score 2):

In VBscript we can use:

```
Dim fso,colDrives,objDrive
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colDrives = fso.Drives
For Each objDrive in colDrives
  Wscript.Echo "Drive letter: " & objDrive.DriveLetter
Next
```

In Powershell you can list drives inside an array with:

```
$drives=gdr -psp FileSystem|select -eXp root
```

Here it selects `root` property which shows like `C:\` where `name` shows like `C`.

To iterate over drives in batch you can use:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic logicalDisk get caption /format:List ^| find /I "caption"') do (
  echo %%~a is your drive letter
  echo Do what you like here
)
```

Comment: You shouldn’t post three separate answers for three different methods. I took the answers you posted [here](https://superuser.com/a/1587154/167207) as well as [here](https://superuser.com/a/1587155/167207) and combined them in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

my approach would be a batch file with a standalone single command, (not external command needed)...

```
echo Available Drives:
for %%v in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist "%%v:\\" echo %%v:
```

Comment: Looks genius and very portable! Thanks.

Comment: @saulius2 my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely love the pure batch method [shown in the answer from cybercontroler](https://superuser.com/a/1691142/167207), all internal commands no less!

I wanted to share my batch edit/modification that based on cybercontroler's answer.

For my current project, I needed to identify which drive labeled as `DATA` so I replaced the echo command with vol (internal command).

I also used the set command to create the variable `[1]` that would contain the full set of capital letters in order to shorten the `for` command's length.

Since `if exist` will be checking for drive letters only, there will never be a space character in this test, so I omitted the double quotes.

Testing the omission the two back slashes yields the same results.

The added command line `@echo off` filtered the output to show results only.

I piped the results to the external `find` command to filter serial number lines created by the vol command.

I placed a pause command so that it wouldn't be necessary to run a "Command Prompt" beforehand in order to see the results when clicking on the batch file.

The results from the original identified all available drive letters mixed in with `for` command processing the full set of capital letters. With `@echo off` filtering, my run displayed:

```
C:
D:
```

The results using vol displays:
Volume in drive C is OS

```
 Volume in drive D is DATA
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here's my batch file which includes both for commands; you can comment-out the for command that you do not want to run by prefixing command lines with two colons (`::`).

#### Batch File

```
echo Available Drives:
for %%v in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist "%%v:\\" 

echo %%-:
@echo off
set [1]=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
for %%- in (%[1]%) do if exist %%-: vol %%-: | find "in drive"
pause
```

Note that this batch method does not identify DVD drives, not sure why. But the command `fsutil fsinfo drives` does. My output reads: `Drives: C:\ D;\ J:\` (`J:\` being my DVD drive.)

Comment: Hi, I'm new to answering.  After I pasted a batch code, lines ran into each other and Giacomo fixed it.  If I pasted batch code in a Code Block will  that preserve my original spacing?  --Bill

Comment: Thanks for noting the DVD exception.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Billy-Boy I didn't thought about that "if exist" wouldn't work with an empty CD/DVD/Card-Reader/etc. drives, it is because "if exist" work on files or directories level, so in empty drives exist nothing, (long time I do not use CD drives)... for the use I need I don't mind empty drives, but would be nice having a code that show empty drives also, although it, for sure, would be not that minimalist...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1135878)