# Storing info from wmic as variables in command prompt (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, usb-flash-drive

I'm trying to write a batch file that copies a folder from my flash drive to the desktop. I want the batch file to achieve this on any pc in my college.

the command `wmic logicaldisk get caption,description` allows to me to find out which drive letter has been assigned to my removable disk.

I need to somehow set the drive letter of my usb disk as a variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use output as VARIABLE and put trimmed value into CLIP?](https://superuser.com/questions/1325420/how-to-use-output-as-variable-and-put-trimmed-value-into-clip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this thread is the solution you are looking for : https://superuser.com/a/139935/395792

Especially the 2nd part of the post.