# CMD set variable to be result of a command

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I would like to run a command to set a computers description. I found that to get the model i can do

```
wmic computersystem get model
```

I am wondering how can i set the result of that line to be a variable called model that will later be part of the computer description?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing info from wmic as variables in command prompt (Windows 7)](https://superuser.com/questions/848216/storing-info-from-wmic-as-variables-in-command-prompt-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

#### how can I set the result of the following command to be a variable called model?

```
wmic computersystem get model
```

The output of this is:

```
Model
VPCF22L1E
```

Note the extra blank line.

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%i in (`wmic computersystem get model`) do (
  set model=%%i
  goto :done
  )
:done
@echo %model%
```

Notes:

- `skip=1` is used to skip the `wmic` header line.
- `goto :done` is use to skip the `wmic` extra blank line.

Example output:

```
F:\test>test
VPCF22L1E

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.