# how to use output as VARIABLE and put trimmed value into CLIP?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, environment-variables

can anyone teach me the right way? here is my attempt code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

"%~dp0..\x64\mediainfo.exe" --Inform=General;%%UniqueID/String%% "%~dp0..\files\SOURCE.avi" | clip
```

this is what I got:

```
272951594390852679981592891584486079797 (0xCD58909D52AF1297B61A0656EC307D35)
```

this is what I need:

```
90852679981592891584486079797 (0xCD58909D52AF1297B61A0656EC30
```

basiclly to strip-off the output (by factor of 10 positions from left and 5 from right) and send it to clipboard. (hope its clear and thank you in advance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to parse the output of mediainfo and store it into a variable before you can strip parts of it.

```
@echo off
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('
  C:\Temp\X\x64\mediainfo.exe --Inform^=General^;%%UniqueID/String%% "C:\Temp\X\files\SOURCE.avi"
') Do set "var=%%A"
Echo=%var:~10,-5%| clip
```

the output should be:

```
90852679981592891584486079797 (0xCD58909D52AF1297B61A0656EC30
```

**EDIT** to elaborate on the issue with mediainfo on the command line:

```
> mediainfo.exe --Inform=General drop.avi
General
Complete name                            : drop.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 660 KiB
Duration                                 : 6 s 67 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 891 kb/s
IsTruncated                              : Yes
...snip...
```

And to capture the output of a special property:

```
> for /f "delims=" %A in ('mediainfo.exe --Inform^=General^;%Format/Info%  drop.avi') do @echo=%A
Audio Video Interleave
```

In a batch file all the percent signs have to be doubled.

Comment: I learned something from this, but no, I need the output as I stated (without ending ")" ) and also I apologize for not mentioning in the post that `SOURCE.avi` needs to be `"%~dp0..\files\SOURCE.avi"` so I tried to redo it but it doesnt work >> `For /f "tokens=1" %%A in ('"%~dp0..\x64\mediainfo.exe" --Inform=General;%%UniqueID/String%% "%~dp0..\files\SOURCE.avi"') Do set "varA=%%A" Echo=%varA:~10,-5% | clip`

Comment: Changed the batch above, the `for /f` needs to escape the `=` and/or `;` in the mediainfo command with a caret `^` to not split into several arguments. That worked here with different arguments for a different .avi file.

Comment: this new one causes error `'C:\Temp\X' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable command or batch file` so I guess that %~dp0 part is not evaluated as it should by FOR ?

Comment: Either change my single quotes `'` to backquotes `\`` or remove the `usebackq`

Comment: It looks like you are always doing one bit different than my examples :-( Where do you save the batch file and where are mediainfo/the avi located?

Comment: batch: `C:\Temp\X\scripts\bat.bat`

mediainfo: `C:\Temp\X\x64\mediainfo.exe`

avi: `C:\Temp\X\files\source.avi` 

and I need to use `%~dp0` in my batch

Comment: I inserted the absolute path's into the batch, please try this last version.

Comment: I am ashamed but this does not work. I copy/paste/saved your latest answer/code and when I run it the clipboard returns me: **~10,-5)**

Comment: It seems to be a weird issue with the `for /f`, the moment there are two double quoted elements in the command it errors out, with only one d'quoted - either mediainfo or the avi it works here.

Comment: would this somehow resolve it if I would use alias before FOR? something like: `set "%~dp0..\x64\mediainfo.exe"=mediainfoalias ` (but this one doesnt work) and then use "alias" in FOR like: `For /f "delims=" %%A in ('
  %mediainfoalias% --Infor...` ??

Comment: That's the wrong way around, try the above version, in the path's are no spaces or other prohibiting chars, so d'quoting isn't required here.

Comment: yes, as you stated, only one pair of "" are processed, still even if this works as provided I am not happy with it, because this is a special case where I need to use  `"%~dp0..\.."`, so I will go with my own solution (provided below), however I am greatfull.

Answer (score 1):

`` value=`http POST localhost:3000/test/login < test/login.json -h |awk ‘/Access-Token/{print $2}` ``

This will put the second value name Access token to a variable `value`

I guess awk is the best way to do what you are trying to `cheers`

Answer (score 0):

unless there is a more "non-re-direct" way (?)...

```
@echo off

"%~dp0..\x64\mediainfo.exe" --Inform=General;%%UniqueID/String%% "%~dp0..\files\SOURCE.avi" > s.txt

set /p var=< s.txt

DEL /Q /F s.txt

echo=%var:~10,-5% | clip
```