# How to list just hard drive partitions on windows (except dvd-drives)?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, wmic

I have a `.bat` file in which there's the following command and can list available drives on my computer :

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do @echo.%%x
```

And give the the following result :

> ```
> C:
> D:
> E:
> J:
> R:
> ```

This link could help me to get all available drives : [See available drives from Windows CLI?](https://superuser.com/questions/139899/see-available-drives-from-windows-cli)

*Now I want to list just available hard drives (letters) not `dvd-rom` or any other else...*

This is my available drives on computer that get them with `diskpart` and then `list volume` commands :

```
 Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
 ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
 Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
 Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition     39 GB  Healthy    System
 Volume 2     J   New Volume   NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy
 Volume 3     E   New Volume   NTFS   Partition     50 MB  Healthy
 Volume 4     R   New Volume   NTFS   Partition    130 MB  Healthy
```

***The main questions :***

- How can I achieve this (to get just hard drives excluding dvd or any other none-storage drives)??
- Also Is it feasible to get all hard drives except *system* drive (I mean windows drive) ??
- In a nutshell, I want drive letters of this list :

  ```
   Volume 2     J   New Volume   NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy
   Volume 3     E   New Volume   NTFS   Partition     50 MB  Healthy
   Volume 4     R   New Volume   NTFS   Partition    130 MB  Healthy
  ```

**Notice : I just want to list drive letters not any more.**

Comment: Nice formatting on your question!

Comment: @spikey_richie Your welcome

Comment: @spikey_richie If its a nice formatting so it Deserving to up-vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get caption
```

Drive Type of 3 = Local Disk

```
0   Unknown
1   No root directory
2   Removable disk
3   Local disk
4   Network drive
5   Compact disk
6   RAM disk
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this could help me but how can I except windows drive (I mean `c` drive) also?

Comment: Maybe drivetype=1? I am on a laptop with an SSD and no partitions, so I can't test multiple scenarios i'm afraid.

Comment: How to add `drivetype=3` and `drivetype != 1`  in wmic?

Comment: I meant where drivetype=1 instead of 3, but I tested it on a VM with 4 drives and it returned 0. I guess you'll need to find some other was to trim/remove C: from the output.